# Haskell parse error on input ‘->’ pattern matching from Bool to String

Tags: haskell

I'm a trying to get into Haskell. The Function itself (without pattern matching) works, but with the pattern matching I get this error:

> error: parse error on input ‘->’ 
>      |  
>   23 | print_is_even ∷ Bool -> String  
>      |

```
print_is_even ∷ Bool -> String
print_is_even x = if x==True then "Is even" else "Not even"
```

Comment: Side note: `x==True` is redundant; you can replace it with `x`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either turn on the `UnicodeSyntax` extension, or use `::` instead of `∷`.